# Calling sparse matrix product in Accelerate

Tags: macos, fortran, accelerate-framework

I often use `Accelerate` framework on macOS to speedup my calculations with matrices. The main program is written in Fortran, and the call to `dgemm` is essentially identical to that of the [documentation](https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/d54/group__double__blas__level3_gaeda3cbd99c8fb834a60a6412878226e1.html) on netlib.

In my current project, great performance improvement is expected from the use of *sparse-dense matrix multiplication*. I found that `Accelerate` contains a `sparse_matrix_product_dense_double` function ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1546216-sparse_matrix_product_dense_doub)). According to the documentation, the function should work on macOS 10.11+ (I have 13.2). Here is my question: is it possible to directly call this function from fortran? My naive tests with gfortran

```
program dgemm_demo
  integer, parameter :: m = 3, n = 4, k = 5 

  double precision, allocatable :: A(:,:), B(:,:), C(:,:)

  allocate(A(m,k), B(k, n), C(m, n))

  A = 1.0D0
  B = 2.0D0

  call dgemm ('N', 'N', M, N, K, 1.0D0, A, m, B, k, 0.0D0, C, m)

  call sparse_matrix_product_dense_double('CblasColMajor', 'CblasTrans', n, 1.0D0,&
    sparse_matrix_create_double(m, k), B, n, C, n)
  
end program dgemm_demo
```

return linking error

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

Comment: Where exactly did you find it? Is it a C function or C++ function or what is it?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава This is a function from a large library (the Accelerate framework). The advantage is that it uses the AMX matrix coprocessor. So far, I've only used the BLAS subset of the library and was pleasantly impressed by its speed. But I am curious to try other functions even if it means writing a wrapper in, say, c++. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with macos native swift or objective-c. Since this is a library, it should be possible to call from at least C++. I added a link to the documentation.

Comment: You can probably try to call it using `bind(C)` but what kind of arguments would you pass? And it is for a sparse matrix and a dense matrix. How do you plan to create the sparse matrix? Do you know the sparse matrix format it uses?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава This is compressed sparse column (CSC) format. There are subroutines for building sparse matrices (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/creating_sparse_matrices). However, I believe I am not so far at the moment. I cannot link and I am worried by the message "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64".

Comment: As I wrote, you can try to link it using `bind(C)`, there are plenty of examples of such interface blocks on this site. However, passing the correct arguments will be tricky.

Comment: Luckily, the sparse routines are more or less pure C (no Objective stuff) so calling the routines using `bind(C)` is straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. Accelerate exposes an API very similar to Sparse BLAS as part of [vecLib](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/veclib?language=objc). (The Sparse BLAS API is defined by the [BLAS Technical Forum](https://netlib.org/blas/blast-forum/).)

Search for `BLAS.h` using Finder to get a full overview of the available routines. You can also locate the header using the command: `$ find /Library/Developer -name BLAS.h`.

As a vendor-agnostic, yet performant, cross-platform Sparse BLAS alternative, you might also consider [librsb](https://librsb.sourceforge.net/).

Here's an example of multiplying a sparse matrix A with a dense matrix B using the Sparse BLAS in Accelerate:

```fortran
! accelerate.f90
!
!   Example of calling Sparse BLAS from Accelerate framework on MacOS
! 
!   Compile using:
! 
!      gfortran -Wall -O2 accelerate.f90 -framework Accelerate
!
program accelerate

use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
implicit none

integer, parameter :: dp = c_double

integer, parameter :: spdim = c_int64_t   ! Sparse Dimension (uint64_t)
integer, parameter :: spstr = c_int64_t   ! Sparse Stride
integer, parameter :: spind = c_int64_t   ! Sparse Index

integer, parameter :: cblas_order = c_int
integer, parameter :: cblas_transpose = c_int

! Transpose flags
integer(cblas_transpose), parameter :: NOTRANS   = 111
integer(cblas_transpose), parameter :: TRANS     = 112
integer(cblas_transpose), parameter :: CONJTRANS = 113

! Order flags
integer(cblas_order), parameter :: ROWMAJOR = 101
integer(cblas_order), parameter :: COLMAJOR = 102

! Sparse Status
integer(c_int), parameter :: SPARSE_SUCCESS             =     0
integer(c_int), parameter :: SPARSE_ILLEGAL_PARAMETER   = -1000
integer(c_int), parameter :: SPARSE_CANNOT_SET_PROPERTY = -1001
integer(c_int), parameter :: SPARSE_SYSTEM_ERROR        = -1002

interface

    !> C = alpha * op(A) * B + C, where A is sparse, B and C are dense
    function dspmm(order,transa,n,alpha,A,B,ldb,C,ldc) &
            bind(c,name="sparse_matrix_product_dense_double")
        import c_int, c_int64_t, c_double, c_ptr
        implicit none
        integer(c_int), value :: order
        integer(c_int), value :: transa
        integer(c_int64_t), value :: n
        real(c_double), value :: alpha
        type(c_ptr), value :: A
        real(c_double) :: B(ldb,*)
        integer(c_int64_t), value :: ldb
        real(c_double) :: C(ldc,*)
        integer(c_int64_t), value :: ldc
        integer(c_int) :: dspmm
    end function

    ! Create sparse matrix of doubles
    function dspcreate(m,n) bind(c,name="sparse_matrix_create_double")
        import c_int64_t, c_ptr
        integer(c_int64_t), value :: m, n
        type(c_ptr) :: dspcreate
    end function

    ! Finalize entry phase
    function spcommit(A) bind(c,name="sparse_commit")
        import c_ptr, c_int
        type(c_ptr), value :: A
        integer(c_int) :: spcommit
    end function

    ! Destroy sparse matrix
    function spdestroy(A) bind(c,name="sparse_matrix_destroy")
        import c_ptr, c_int
        type(c_ptr), value :: A
        integer(c_int) :: spdestroy
    end function

    ! Insert into array in triplet format
    function dspinsert_entries(A,n,val,indx,jndx) &
            bind(c,name="sparse_insert_entries_double")
        import c_ptr, c_int64_t, c_double, c_int
        type(c_ptr), value :: A
        integer(c_int64_t), value :: n
        real(c_double), intent(in) :: val(n)
        integer(c_int64_t), intent(in) :: indx(n), jndx(n)
        integer(c_int) :: dspinsert_entries
    end function

end interface

real(dp) :: A(3,3), B(3,3)
integer :: i

real(dp) :: VA(5), C(3,3)
integer(spdim) :: IA(5), JA(5), nnzA
type(c_ptr) :: spA

!
! Dense matrix multiplication
!

A = reshape([1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1],[3,3])
B = reshape([(i,i=1,9)],[3,3])

write(*,'(A,/,3(F10.3,2X))') "Dense result = ", matmul(A,B)

!
! Sparse matrix multiplication
!

nnzA = 5
VA = [ 1, 1,    &
          1,    &
       1,    1]

IA = [1,1,2,3,3] - 1    ! Zero-based indexing expected!
JA = [1,2,2,1,3] - 1

! Initialize matrix of size nrows x ncols
spA = dspcreate(3_spdim,3_spdim)
if (.not. c_associated(spA)) error stop "Sparse matrix creation failed."

! Insert entries from a list of triplets
call spcheck( dspinsert_entries(spA,nnzA,VA,IA,JA) )

! Finalize entry phase by committing
call spcheck( spcommit(spA) )

C = 0.0_dp

! Multiply sparse matrix A with dense matrix B
! Result is stored in C
!
call spcheck( dspmm(COLMAJOR,NOTRANS,3_spdim,1.0_dp,spA,B,3_spdim,C,3_spdim) )
call spcheck( spdestroy(spA) )

write(*,'(/,A,/,3(F10.3,2X))') "Sparse result = ", C

contains

    subroutine spcheck(ierr)
        integer(c_int), intent(in) :: ierr
        
        if (ierr == SPARSE_SUCCESS) &
            return

        write(*,'(A,I0)') 'Error encountered: IERR = ', ierr
        select case(ierr)
        case(SPARSE_ILLEGAL_PARAMETER)
            write(*,'(A)') '  Operation was not completed because one or more'
            write(*,'(A)') '  of the arguments had an illegal value.'
        case(SPARSE_CANNOT_SET_PROPERTY)
            write(*,'(A)') '  Matrix properties can only be set before any'
            write(*,'(A)') '  values are inserted into the matrix.'
        case(SPARSE_SYSTEM_ERROR)
            write(*,'(A)') '  An internal error has occured, such as'
            write(*,'(A)') '  not enough memory.'
        case default
            write(*,'(A)') '  Unknown error code.'
            error stop 1
        end select

    end subroutine

end program
```

Comment: Amazing answer! Exactly I was looking for. Thank you very much. The reference to the BLAS technical is very useful too. (+)